# Dynamic assign correct type to object key value pair

Tags: typescript

I have a object like this:

```
export const typedGetters = {
  [GettersE.login]: (state: RootState) => state.loggedIn,
}
```

I try to create an object where i the key stays the same, and the value is the return value of the Function.

```
{
  test: () => "test"
  foo: () => DataType as DataT
}
```

The type should be

```
{
   test: string
   foo: DataT
}
```

Here is what i tried

```
  let getters = store.getters as {
    [key in keyof typeof typedGetters]: ReturnType<
      (typeof typedGetters)[keyof typeof typedGetters]
    >
  }
```

Currently every key inside my object has every value, combined with logical OR

[image]

In this example `login` should be `boolean`

Comment: What's `GettersE`/`RootState`/`DataType`/`DataT`/etc?  Could you provide a [mre] that we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing?  Otherwise it's hard to get started.

Comment: This still has a lot of the same issues as your (now deleted) [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395967/dynamic-return-type-of-values-of-function). This has more detail than that but still doesn't address all the issues. Like why you're **using an unsafe cast instead of a simple type annotation on your variable**.

Answer (score 2):

```
  let getters = store.getters as {
    [key in keyof typeof typedGetters]: ReturnType<
      (typeof typedGetters)[key]
      //                    ^^^
    >
  }
```

Comment: Perfekt, exactly what i need

Comment: how can i call it like `getters.login` instead of `getters["login"]` ?